# Get TinyMCE 4.3 Image Tools to save images as regular image files

Tags: tinymce-4

The new TinyMCE 4.3 Image Tools (eg when cropping) saves images as blob data instead of image files in a directory. the edited mage url is like

blob:http://www.example.com/f2953aa1-e64f-49e1-a6e3-a283986663bf

I want to upload the image file to a specific folder and then use it as regular image referance / path.

**Note**
The question I am going to put is similar to [Image edit issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134186/tinymce-4-2-get-the-new-core-image-tools-to-save-api-edited-images-as-file). but the answer to this question is not working. I also tried http://archive.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=35740 solution but not working because it produces always same name image name.

Answer (score 2):

The basic process is that TinyMCE will create a separate HTTP POST for each image that you modify with the image editor. It will send that image to a URL of your choosing (via HTTP POST) based on the setting of the `images_upload_url` option in your init.

The image handler at the URL referenced in the `images_upload_url` (which you have to create) has to do whatever needs to be done to "store" the image in your application. That could mean something like:

- Store the item in a folder on your web server
- Store the item in a database
- Store the item in an asset management system

...regardless of where you choose to store the image your image handler needs to return a single line of JSON telling TinyMCE the new location of the image. As referenced in the TinyMCE documentation this might look like:

{ location : '/uploaded/image/path/image.png' }

TinyMCE will then update the image's src attribute to the value you return. If you use the `images_upload_base_path setting` in the init that will be prepended to the returned location. The TinyMCE page has more details on all of this:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/handle-async-image-uploads/

The net here is that TinyMCE knows when an embedded image exists in your content but it can't possibly know what to do with that image in the context of your application so that job (the "image handler") is something you must create.

Comment: The POST info comes into the defined url when the "Edit Image" button is used along with "Apply" then "Save".  But nothing seams to fire when using the other options like rotate, flip-horizontal etc...  Those options do change the image and do give off another unique blob://http url with its own unique marker.  Is there a different location where those are POSTed to?

Comment: Found the answer, the others do get posted to but not until the image looses focus, probably to prevent an image save on every step of the rotate.  Thanks very much.